# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object for list

Tags: python

I have a list which contains the frame, start codon position, stop codon position, sequence of the gene, and gene length . Both sequence and length are based on the start and stop. I wanted to unpack this list and add frame, start/stop positions, sequence, and gene length for genes with a certain length to another list. My code is as follows:

```
for framenumber, startposition, stopposition, geneseq, genelength in range(len(codonpairsfwd)):
    if len(gene_seq) < 200:
        GenesToRemove_Fwd.append(framenumber)
        GenesToRemove_Fwd.append(startposition)
        GenesToRemove_Fwd.append(stopposition)
        GenesToRemove_Fwd.append(geneseq)
        GenesToRemove_Fwd.append(genelength)
```

and I get this error message:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object for the first line(i.e. line with for loop).

Any ideas where I might be going wrong would super appreciated

Comment: You are trying to get 5 values out of `framenumber, startposition, stopposition, geneseq, genelength in range(len(codonpairsfwd))`. This is not how range works. Have a look at the basics. If your list already includes at indice one a tuple of those 5 desired variable, then directly iterate over the list `for v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 in L:`

Answer (score 1):

range() will list numbers (int) to loop, so you cannot unpack that number onto framenumber, startposition, stopposition, ... etc... as it's only an integer, starting from 0 and ends with len(codonparisfwd).

Comment: what do you suggest I use? when I don't use range, I get the same error?

Comment: I dont know the structure of codonpairsfwd, but maybe:

for framenumber, startposition, stopposition, geneseq, genelength in codonpairsfwd:

Comment: how does the data look like in codonpairsfwd ?

Comment: update the problem was that I needed a list of tuples instead to make up my codonpairsfwd list. (i.e. I had to append this variables together as a tuple when populating my list and append them as such when filtering my list!

Comment: You can iterate through a list of tuples like that:
for x,y in [(1,2), (2,3)]:
   print(x, y)